# How to prevent elements from shifting upwards on vertical window resize?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, overflow, responsiveness

I am creating a React.js app, but this is mostly a CSS question.

How do I prevent my objects from shifting upwards when I resize a window vertically? Whenever you take a look at most commercial websites, whenever the window shrinks vertically, no elements shift, instead you get a scroll bar to just scroll all the content. My problem is, that with my hamburger menu on mobile, or smaller screens, the menu shifts upwards and overlaps my navbar. How can I prevent  that?

My Navbar Component:

```
 return ( 
        <nav className={Styles.navbar}>
            <Link to='/'>
                <img src='/src\images\logo-color.png'/>
            </Link>
                <ul className={`${Styles.navlinks} ${mobileNavClass}`}>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink onClick={toggleMobileMenu} to='/'>
                            HOME
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink onClick={toggleMobileMenu} to='/menu'>
                            MENU
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink onClick={toggleMobileMenu} to='/signin'>
                            SIGN&nbsp;IN
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <div className={Styles.iconcontainer}>
                    <div onClick={toggleMobileMenu} className={Styles.hamburger}>
                        {!mobileMenuOpen ? (<RxHamburgerMenu className={Styles.hamburgericon}/>) : (<RxCross2 className={Styles.hamburgericon}/>)}
                    </div>
                    <div className={Styles.cart}>
                        <NavLink onClick={handleCartClick} to='/cart'>
                            <AiOutlineShoppingCart className={Styles.carticon}/>
                        </NavLink>
                    </div>
                </div>

               
        </nav>
     );
```

This is my CSS module:

```
img {
   height: 116px;
   width: 116px;
   margin-left: 2rem;
   z-index: 100;
   user-select: none;
}

 li {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
 }

 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #414241;
    font-family: 'Burnest', sans-serif;
 }

.navbar {
   top: 0;
   height: 120px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   padding: 0.5rem;
   z-index: 10;
   position: sticky;
   z-index: 9999;
}

.navlinks {
   margin-right: 2rem;
   gap: 4rem;
   margin-top: 2.5rem;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   list-style: none;
 }

 .iconcontainer {
   display: flex;
   gap: 1rem;
 }

 .hamburger {
   display: none;
   align-items: center;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

 .hamburgericon {
   height: 32px;
   width: 32px;
   margin-top: -4px;
   color: #414241;
 }

 .cart {
   margin-right: 1rem;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   margin-top: -8px;
   color: #414241;
 }

 .carticon {
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

   img {
      margin-left: 0; 
      height: 80px;
      width: 80px;
   }

   ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
   }

   li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
   }

   .navbar {
      height: 100px;
   }

   .navlinks {
      position: fixed;
      top: 8%;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      gap: 6rem;
      z-index: 9998;
      transform: translateX(120vw);
      overflow-y: scroll;
   }

   .navmobile {
      transform: none;
   }

   .cart {
      margin-top: -2px;
    }

   li {
      height: 3rem;
   }

   .hamburger {
      display: flex;
   }   

   body {
      overflow: hidden;
   }

 }
```

I guess I'm just not sure which property causes my elements to shift, or perhaps which one to use in order to prevent it?

I've tried putting all my content in a wrapper and giving it a fixed width, did not seem to work. My body has margin and padding set to 0.

Some pictures to help visualize:

Works great on this size: [correct display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0VVJ.png)

Overlaps and doesn't give a scrollbar on vertical shrink: [incorrect display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU8Ft.png)

Answer (score 0):

wrap the logo and the ul in a div tag so that inside your nav tag you will have two div tag. in you nav tag styling: display: flex, flex-direction: column;

Comment: Unfortunately, the menu under my navbar on smaller device still ends up shifting upwards when I vertically shrink the window. Not sure what's causing it.

Comment: can you paste the new edited code for me

Comment: from your css code in the media queries the height of the navbar is 100px the height of the image is 80px the height of the li is 3rem = 16 * 3 = 48px. the image and the li are inside the navbar 80 plus 48 is more than 100px the. the elements in the navbar will force to fit

Comment: Even with a larger height on navbar it happens. I'm assuming the issue lies within the position being fixed. With position relative, the page acts the way i want it to on vertical shrinking of window, however I cannot position my burger menu in the middle covering most of the page. I ended up adding some picutres to better display what's happening and what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: the div covering the handbuger and the cart is it 100% of the screen. if so and you what both the handburger and cart to be in the middle the use flex properties.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, but making it fixed or absolute seems to be an issue. Not sure if I somehow can position my menu in the center and make it cover the entire screen without position fixed.

Comment: if you are using position: absolute for the handburger menu then the parent component must be position: relative. absolute and relative work together. don't use position: fixed. preferably use position: sticky. then center the handburger with the left and top styling rules. e.g position: sticky; top: 50%; left: 50%; . if you are still confused read about position style rule of css

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers, I'll check out your latest suggestion in a bit!